# firebase_messaging how to clear notification?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) 
When notification comes, I'm displaying alert dialog. Below are my code.

```
showNotification(BuildContext context) {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
        _showPushNotificationDialog(message['notification']['title'],
            message['notification']['body'], context);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
        _showPushNotificationDialog(
            message['data']['title'], message['data']['body'], context);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
        _showPushNotificationDialog(
            message['data']['title'], message['data']['body'], context);
      },
    );
  }
```

Where `_showPushNotificationDialog` method will call each times when **onMessage**, **onResume**, and **onLaunch** method call.

Facing issue like when my app is in background or terminate mode and notification will come and will tap on notification tray all works good.  But when I go on other page and come back to previous one all time `_firebaseMessaging.configure(....` method call and its has data so each time my alert dialog pups up.

So how can I clear notification that was clicked by notification tray?

Comment: did you found a solution, I have the same issue @govaadiyo

Comment: Sorry, Nope @EvripidesKyriacou

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems with this too. I have this workaround:
What i did was to create a class with an static bool and static method:

```
class MessagingWidget {

  static bool _isConfigured = false;


  static void configuringFirebase(User currentUser, BuildContext context){
      

      final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
      if (!_isConfigured) {
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        final notification = message['notification'];
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");

        final notification = message['data'];
        if(notification['title']!=null){
            if(notification['title']=="Testo"){
              goToAppointmentsScreen(currentUser,context);

            }
          }
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");

        final notification = message['data'];
        if(notification['title']!=null){
            if(notification['title']=="Testo"){
              goToAppointmentsScreen(currentUser,context);

            }
          }
      },
    );
    _isConfigured = true;
    }

  }
    
    
  }

  void goToAppointmentsScreen(User currentUser1, BuildContext context1) async {
    final bool backFromAppointmentsScreen=await Navigator.push(
            context1,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Appointment( 
              currentUser1),
            ),
            );
  }
```

Then I called this method in my init from the routing widget:

```
@override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    refreshServices();
    getDirectionBasedOnLocation();
    MessagingWidget.configuringFirebase(currentUser, context);
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: It is not the best solution, but it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's a bit ugly, but I know only this way:

1. add [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)
2. `import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';`

3. Just create `final fln = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();`
4. and use `fln.cancelAll()` when you need.

Answer (score 1):

What I do to prevent onLaunch and onResume method to run again and again is to check the current notification with the last notification (I use shared_preferences)

Here's the snippet:

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on message $message');
      onMessageReceived(context, message);
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on resume $message');
      onLaunch(context, message);
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on launch $message');
      onLaunch(context, message);
    },
  );

.
.
.

void onLaunch(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> remoteMessage) async {
  var pref = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  var data = remoteMessage['data'] ?? remoteMessage;
  String lastData = '';

  await pref.then((prefs) {
    lastData = prefs.get('remote_message');
  });

  if ((data['type'] != null || data['id'] != null) &&
      data.toString() != lastData) {

    toDetailPageFromPush(
      context,
      data['type'],
      data['id'],
    );
    pref.then((prefs) {
      prefs.setString('remote_message', data.toString());
    });
  } else {
    print('on launch error $remoteMessage');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, using the **message_id** which is and unique value from the notification, so we can save  the last id of the notification using shared prefrerences and compare with the current notification:

```
processNotification(message, BuildContext context) async {
 try {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 
  String lastMessageId = sharedPreferences.getString('last_message_id');
  String currentMessageId = message['data']['google.message_id'];

  //COMPARE NOTIFICATIONS ID
  if(currentMessageId != lastMessageId) {
    
     //SET LAST NOTIFICATION ID
     sharedPreferences.setString('last_message_id', currentMessageId);
 
     //SHOW A DIALOG OR NAVIGATE TO SOME VIEW, IN THIS CASE TO A VIEW
     String screen = message['data']['screen'];
     Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(screen);
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('ERROR PROCESSING NOTIFICATION');
  print(e);
 }
}
```

Now we can call this function in the config:

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on message $message');
    processNotification(context,message);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on resume $message');
    processNotification(context,message);
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    processNotification(context,message);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to configure the firebaseMessaging in initState instead of in a custom method. That should work :)

Comment: This method calling from initState :)

Comment: @Govaadiyo : Maybe i ran into the same problem as you did (now i think i might misunderstood your initial question). I opened a github issue but didn’t get an answer from the official flutter devs. Nonetheless, i found a workaround which seems to work for me. Maybe it helps you as well? You can find my problem and my work around here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32698#issuecomment-494766329